# Order of parameters in a method generated from Swagger/OpenAPI definition

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi, swagger-codegen

A bit of context. In my system ServiceB calls ServiceA. The ServiceA provides a Swagger/OpenAPI definition, which ServiceB uses to generate its client code.

ServiceA requires some custom header parameters that are added to GroupedOpenAPI by addOperationCustomizer method.

```
@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi opeApiDefinitionBuilder() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
        .addOperationCustomizer(zzzHeaderParameterAdder)
        .addOperationCustomizer(yyyHeaderParameterAdder)
        .addOperationCustomizer(xxxHeaderParameterAdder)
        .build();
        }
 
// where xxxHeaderParameterAdder and others are an instance of

@Component
public class YYYHeaderParameterAdder implements OperationCustomizer {

  @Override
  public Operation customize(Operation operation, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {

    Parameter extraParam = new Parameter()
        .in(ParameterIn.HEADER.toString())
        .name("parameterXXX")
        .schema(new Schema().type("string"))
        .required(Boolean.TRUE);

    operation.addParametersItem(extraParam);

    return operation;
  }
}
```

when Spring Boot 2 with springdoc-openapi-ui was used, then the genreated swagger definition contains defined parameter added in the revers order of operation registration (Query comes from endpoind definition).

```
        "parameters" : [
          {
            "name" : "id",
            "in" : "query",
            "required" : true,
            "schema" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
          },
          {
            "name" : "parameterXXX",
            "in" : "header",
            "required" : true,
            "schema" : {
              "type" : "string"
            }
          },
          {
            "name" : "parameterYYY",
            "in" : "header",
            "required" : true,
            "schema" : {
              "type" : "string"
            }
          },
          {
            "name" : "parameterZZZ",
            "in" : "header",
            "required" : false,
            "schema" : {
              "type" : "string"
            }
          }
```

so gernerated client code looks this way:

```
getWhatever(String id, String parameterXXX, String parameterYYY, String parameterZZZ) { body here}
```

after upgrading to Spring Boot 3 and switching to springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui the order of parameters is reversed

```
        "parameters" : [
          {
            "name" : "id",
            "in" : "query",
            "required" : true,
            "schema" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
          },
          {
            "name" : "parameterZZZ",
            "in" : "header",
            "required" : false,
            "schema" : {
              "type" : "string"
            }
          },
          {
            "name" : "parameterYYY",
            "in" : "header",
            "required" : true,
            "schema" : {
              "type" : "string"
            }
          },
          {
            "name" : "parameterXXX",
            "in" : "header",
            "required" : true,
            "schema" : {
              "type" : "string"
            }
          }
```

what results in different client code

```
getWhatever(String id, String parameterZZZ, String parameterYYY, String parameterXXX) { body here}
```

to summ up

```
// new client generated code
getWhatever(String id, String parameterZZZ, String parameterYYY, String parameterXXX) { body here}
// old client generated code
getWhatever(String id, String parameterXXX, String parameterYYY, String parameterZZZ) { body here}
```

compiler cannot detect this error because all parameters are strings.

The io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Operation class has no property that allows to manipulate the order of operations. How to deal with this problem?

Comment: We found the same issue after upgrading to Spring Boot 3. Did you find a solution for this?